# how to use js to submit the formdata which from the html page

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

Here is my question:

I write a register.htm document with html. but when i try to use JS to return the data that people write to the current page. it doesn`t work. i fill in the form,and press the button"提交",but nothing return to my page. which code is wrong? what can i do with the code?

*please help me to use the JS implement return all value(include:name、sex、initData) for this html document.*

**3Q for you help**

---

and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="注册" />
<title>注册</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var sumbit = function(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var sex = document.getElementById("sex").value;
    var form = document.getElementById("form1").value;
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initDate(year,month,day) {
<!--
            //每个月的初始天数
　　        MonDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
　　        //当前的年份
　　        var y = new Date().getFullYear();
　　        //当前的月份
　　        var m = new Date().getMonth()+1; //javascript月份为0-11
　　        //当前的天份
　　        var d = new Date().getDate();　    
            //以今年为准，向后50年，填充年份下拉框
　　        for (var i = y; i >(y-50); i--)
            {
　　            year.options.add(new Option(i,i));
            }
            //选中今年
            year.value=y;

　　        //填充月份下拉框
　　        for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                month.options.add(new Option(i,i));
            }
            //选中当月
            month.value = m     
            //获得当月的初始化天数
            var n = MonDays[m-1];
            //如果为2月，天数加1
            if (m == 2 && isLeapYear(year.options[year.selectedIndex].value))
                  n++;
            //填充日期下拉框
            createDay(n,day); 
            //选中当日
            day.value = new Date().getDate();
　　    }
function change(year,month,day) //年月变化，改变日，当鼠标点击select时触发onclick事件从而调用此函数
　　    {
　　         var y = year.options[year.selectedIndex].value;                 

             //由于传递参数的是调用的this指针，
    　　     var m = month.options[month.selectedIndex].value;
    　　     //if (m == "" ){  clearOptions(day); return;}
    　　     var n = MonDays[m - 1];
    　　     if ( m ==2 && isLeapYear(y))
    　　     {
    　　         n++;
    　　     }
    　　     createDay(n,day)
　　    }
function createDay(n,day) //填充日期下拉框
　　    {
　　        //清空下拉框
    　　     clearOptions(day);
    　　     //几天，就写入几项
    　　     for(var i=1; i<=n; i++)
    　　     {
    　　        day.options.add(new Option(i,i));
    　　     }
　　    }
function clearOptions(ctl)//删除下拉框中的所有选项
　　    {
            for(var i=ctl.options.length-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
　　            ctl.remove(i);
　　         }
　　    }　
function isLeapYear(year)//判断是否闰年
　　    { 
　　        return( year%4==0 || (year0 ==0 && year%400 == 0));
　　    }
function onload() { 
          initDate(document.form1.select_year,document.form1.select_month,document.form1.select_day);
          //初始化出生日期下拉菜单内容
}//-->

</script>
            <style>
                 body{
                 font-family:"幼圆";
                 font-size:18px; 
            }
            </style> 
</head>




<body onload="onload()">

<center>
<table>
  <hr>
             <caption style="text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;color:#444693">
                  <h1>注册</h1>
             </caption>

           <tr><td>姓名：</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td></tr>
           <tr><td>性别：</td><td><input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" checked>男<input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" checked>女</td></tr>
           <tr>
               <td align="right">出生日期：</td>
                 <td>
                 <form name="form1" id="form1">
                    <select name="select_year" onchange="change(this,document.form1.select_month, document.form1.select_day)">
                    </select>年
                    <select name="select_month" onchange="change(document.form1.select_year, this,document.form1.select_day)">
                    </select>月 
                    <select name="select_day"></select>日
                 </form>
                 </td>
           </tr>
</table>
            <input type="button" value="提交" onclick="sumbit();" />
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WHY ARE YOU YELLING AT ME?**

Comment: +1 because I'm compiling since two hours and are bored and found it a bit funny, @qwertynl

Comment: Where is your server-side code?

Comment: I just write this code。because i`m not very clear about JS

Comment: **-1** not enough jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start by making a few clarifications to the user, you should study how to work with javascript and jQuery, you cannot try to build up something and, if it's not working, ask here. This is a little help that could address you in a quite-right way.

Substitute your submit input with this:

```
<input type="submit" id="sendform" value="Send">
```

Then, PLEASE, add jQuery from CDN in the  section of your page, then try this code (add what is missing, like code for name and sex...):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#sendform").click(function() {
          var year = $("select[name=select_year]:selected").val();
          var month = $("select[name=select_month]:selected").val();
          var day = $("select[name=select_day]:selected").val();   
          $.get("page.php",{'year': year, 'month': month... })
          .done(function(msg) {
              alert("do whatever you want with the php response in "+msg);
          });       
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: First of all,Thank you for you kind.and i add jQuery from CDN in my page.and try you code.but it still return nothing,and the console shows:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.  am i still wrong with some code? could you help me implement all of this?

Comment: I should know what you wrote on the php page... Then, all the js code has to be put between the $(document).ready function...
Review your html code, check that every input is connected so something in the js code, then ask. Paste your complete code on jsFiddle when you're done.

Comment: sorry,Perhaps, I wasn't too clear about what I had meant. Let me try and clear this up a bit：I try to just use "html+JS" to implement the purpose which is the JS code to Get the data from the html and alert all of them.by the way,I`ve no Php page.i just want use js and html.thank for you kind.could you do me a favor?

Comment: How do you think to save the registration data without php?

Comment: Do you just want to alert (with alert()) the user with data he has just inserted? In that case, you can save every val using the part of code in my answer (After click(function()) and in the end alert the user with alert("name: "+var1+" - value2: "+val2) etc.

Comment: I solve the problem，thank you for you idea！it gives me another idea，i can`t be more grateful  @Alberto

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider fixing your code, for example, specifying the action and method in your form, for the sake of simplicity I'll just answer you how to submit the form(withouth jQuery):

Just change your submit function:

```
var sumbit = function(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var sex = document.getElementById("sex").value;
    document.getElementById("form1").submit(); //submit form
  }
```

Comment: thank for you advice，i fixed it with you code, but it still return nothing to the webpage.should i write another JS document?